# Finding users who has signed between given dates using Mongoose

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, express, mongoose

I have user model like this

```
const guestSchema = mongoose.Schema({
  facebook: {
    id: String,
    token: String,
    email: String,
    name: String,
    phone: String,
    dates: [
      {
        type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId,
        ref: "loginDate"
      }
    ]
  }
});
```

and loginDate model

```
const loginDateSchema = mongoose.Schema({
  loginDate: Date
});
```

Every time user signs in current Date is added.
How can I find users who have signed in between given date?
I did below but I am getting empty result

```
Guest.find({ "facebook.id": { $exists: true } })
      .populate("facebook.dates")
      .find({ "facebook.dates": { $gte: startDate,$lte: endDate } })
      .exec((err, foundUsers) => {
        res.render("./admin/send", {
          facebookUsers: foundUsers
        });
      });
```

Sample JSON

```
{ 
    "_id" : ObjectId("5a1a838f58eb1a50c408de84"), 
    "facebook" : {
        "email" : "sample@yahoo.com", 
        "name" : "Sample user", 
        "id" : "12345", 
        "dates" : [
            ObjectId("5a1a838f58eb1a50c408de85"), 
            ObjectId("5a1a839258eb1a50c408de86"), 
            ObjectId("5a1a839358eb1a50c408de87"), 
            ObjectId("5a1a839758eb1a50c408de88"), 
            ObjectId("5a1aa17058eb1a50c408de8b")
        ]
    }, 
    "__v" : NumberInt(5)
}
```

LoginDate

```
{ 
    "_id" : ObjectId("5a1a839358eb1a50c408de87"), 
    "loginDate" : ISODate("2017-11-26T09:04:19.107+0000"), 
    "__v" : NumberInt(0)
}
```

Comment: Please post document's json.

Comment: Updated as requested. Thank you

Answer (score 0):

I think the issue is with your date which you are passing into find function on line

```
 .find({ "facebook.dates": { $gte: startDate,$lte: endDate } })
```

You need to pass a date object and not a date string.

Here is my solution which is working fine for me

Facebook model

```
var mongoose = require('mongoose');
var Schema = mongoose.Schema;

mongoose.Promise = global.Promise;

var facebookSchema = new Schema({
    id: String,
    token: String,
    email: String,
    name: String,
    phone: String,
    logindate: Date
},
    {
        versionKey: false 
    }
);

module.exports = mongoose.model('Facebook', facebookSchema);
```

Here is data

```
[  
   {  
      "_id":"5a2949d40591a2192c8fad6b",
      "logindate":"2016-10-10T06:28:37.146Z",
      "phone":"03006351611",
      "name":"mainuhassan",
      "email":"mainuhassan@gmail.com",
      "token":"MxuXmblL56aqt17aHh1rqcyeHc0E4CwQ",
      "id":"100"
   },
   {  
      "_id":"5a294cd26c3e661514f3699e",
      "logindate":"2015-10-10T06:28:37.146Z",
      "phone":"03006351611",
      "name":"mainuhassan1",
      "email":"mainuhassan1@gmail.com",
      "token":"MxuXmblL56aqt17aHh1rqcyeHc0E4CwQ",
      "id":"100"
   },
   {  
      "_id":"5a294cfe75e2ba2778e9f249",
      "logindate":"2017-10-10T06:28:37.146Z",
      "phone":"03006351612",
      "name":"mainuhassan2",
      "email":"mainuhassan2@gmail.com",
      "token":"MxuXmblL56aqt17aHh1rqcyeHc0E4CwQ",
      "id":"100"
   }
]
```

And here is my code for getting data between dates

```
Facebook.find({ logindate: { "$gte": new Date("2016-10-10T06:28:37.146Z"), "$lte": new Date("2017-10-10T06:28:37.146Z") } })   
    .exec(function(error, facebook){
        if (!error) {
            res.send(facebook);
        } 
});
```